# Characteristic function for density $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2(1 + \vert x \vert)^2}, x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: integration, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ with the density
$$
     f_X(x) = \dfrac{1}{2(1 + \vert x \vert)^2}
$$
I want to find the characteristic function $\varphi_X(t)$. Here is what I've done:
$$
    \begin{align*}
          \varphi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right] &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{e^{itx}}{2(1 + \vert x \vert)^2}dx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \dfrac{e^{itx}}{2(1 + x)^2}dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{e^{itx}}{2(1 - x)^2}dx\\
&= \left[\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos(tx)}{2(1 + x)^2}dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{\cos(tx)}{2(1 - x)^2}dx\right] + i \left[\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(tx)}{2(1 + x)^2}dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{\sin(tx)}{2(1 - x)^2}dx\right]\\
&= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos(tx)}{(1 + x)^2}dx
    \end{align*}
$$
If $t = 0$, it is easy to check that then $\varphi_X(t) = 1$. Assume $t > 0$, then, by letting $v = tx$, the integral above becomes:
$$
     \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos(tx)}{(1 + x)^2}dx = t \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\cos v}{(v + t)^2}dv
$$
And here is where I'm getting stuck at. Any hints would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The result is not elementary and is called a Kummer function.  See Abramovitz and Stegun for the integrals $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-zx}x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^c}dx.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use integration by parts to express $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(tx)}{(1+x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx $ in terms of the [sine integral function $\operatorname{Si}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) and the [cosine integral function $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral).

Assume that $t > 0$.

Then we have

$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(tx)}{(1+x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(t(y-1 \right)}{y^{2}} \, \mathrm dy \\ &= - \frac{1}{y} \, \cos \left(t(y-1) \right) \Bigg|_{1}^{\infty}- t \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(t(y-1) \right)}{y} \, \mathrm dy \\&  = 1 - t \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(t(y-1) \right)}{y} \, \mathrm dy \\ & =1 - t \cos(t)\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ty)}{y}  \, \mathrm dy +t \sin(t) \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ty)}{y} \, \mathrm dy \\ & = 1 - t \cos(t) \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (u)}{u} \mathrm du + t\sin(t) \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (u)}{u} \, \mathrm du \\ &=1 - t \cos(t) \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \operatorname{Si}(t) \right) - t\sin(t) \operatorname{Ci}(t). \end{align}$$

This is the same result that [Wolfram Alpha returns](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+cos%28t*x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2++from+x%3D+0+to+infinity%2C+assuming+t+%3E+0).

Comment: It also agrees with what Maple returns.